# What is a good method for decrypting a packet being sent from a client over a local network? (Possible wireshark?)

Tags: c#, networking, hex, wireshark, packet

At the moment I am working on a C# project that processes packets being sent from the client using a `PacketReader` I created. I log the packet and data being sent from the client into a textbox, but how do i really understand what is being sent?

Here is an example of one of the packets:

```
Client->Server
06 00 FD FF 3A 1A                                   ....:.
```

What I really don't understand is the data to the right of the hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably "decoding", not "decrypting" the data.

The client sends a message to the server. You see it sends `06 00 FD FF 3A 1A`.

It could mean anything and nothing.

E.g. the server and client could be programmed to encode "dolphin" as `06` and then `00 FD FF` as padding / delimiter and `3A 1A` as payload meaning `thanks for all the fish`.

Try sending various inputs from your client to your server, changing known parts of the message and see how your packets change.

Oh, and: Good luck!

PS: The `....:.` is an ASCII representation of your hex values on the left. `.` usually indicates that there is no printable character for the ASCII character of the respective value.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark trying to treate the hex as ASCII and print it.

But in ASCII only 0x20 ~ 0x7E is printable, other hex would be displayed as ...

For reference: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstext2pcap.html